# Difference between two array of objects in C#

Tags: .net, linq

I have a list of objects called  input...

I take this list and filter it to get another list of objects Output.

I want to check if the Output list has any changes as compared to the input list..

Both the list are of the same type

Comment: So basically you want to know if the filter matches anything?

Comment: please share us some of your code thank you

Comment: Are there only two lists?

Comment: the list has a field IsActive...when I process the list, the value of IsActive might change...I want to find out in which of the objects the field has changed..

Comment: `list.Where(p=>p.IsActive)` - we need more info

Comment: No...sambomartin...I want to separate the objects which have this field changed...I want to compare the two list's and find out which of the objects have the IsActive field changed...

Comment: You're still not providing us any code to work with. We don't know your problem space.

Comment: @Eldho how could you know that?

Comment: IMHO sorry if my language was rude

Answer (score 0):

```
var nonintersect = modifiedList.Except(originalList);
```

and you need to implement comparer by isActive field

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IEquality Comparer` for this

This is generic implementation of IEquality

```
public class GenericEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T, T, bool> _equalsFunction;
    private Func<T, int> _hashCodeFunction;

    public GenericEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equalsFunction, Func<T, int> hashCodeFunction)
    {
        if (equalsFunction == null) throw new ArgumentException();
        if (hashCodeFunction == null) throw new ArgumentException();

        _equalsFunction = equalsFunction;
        _hashCodeFunction = hashCodeFunction;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _equalsFunction(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _hashCodeFunction(obj);
    }
}
```

Sample usage

```
var difference = List1.Except(list2, new GenericEqualityComparer<Product>((x, y) => x.IsActive== y.IsActive && y.Id== y.Id, x => x.ID.GetHashCode()));
```

Take a look at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx)